# Клонирование репозитория git в текущую папку

Tags: git, github

У меня хостинг timeweb, через панель управления создаю новый сайт, привязываю к нему домен, начинаю работать. По умолчанию для сайта создаётся папка с именем сайта **site** содержащая **public_html** т.е. корневую папку сайта и демо файлы которые можно сразу удалять, что я обычно и делаю.

Проблема вот в чём, есть существующий проект на github я через putty захожу в очищенную от демок директорию нового сайта **site/public_html/** выполняю следующие команды:

```
git init
git clone https://github.com/maler1988/cookies.git
```

клонируется репозиторий в результате в **site/public_html/** создаётся папка **cookies** содержащая файлы фреймворка, `index.php` и пр., то есть те файлы, которые я бы хотел видеть в корне **public_html**. Как это можно сделать без использования трюков c `.htaccess` и пр.?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
git clone https://github.com/maler1988/cookies.git .
```

точка в конце обозначает, что нужно клонировать репозиторий в текущую папку

Comment: и я так понял что git init при клонировании делать не надо?

Comment: git init не надо

Comment: Вы там поаккуратнее с такими штуками:  [http://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/Git-на-сервере-Протоколы#Протокол-HTTP/S](http://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/Git-на-сервере-Протоколы#Протокол-HTTP/S), http://habrahabr.ru/post/70330/

Comment: Директория должны быть пустой!