# Делал изменения не сделав git clone - как теперь залить изменения?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, git, git-commit

Короче, пользуюсь гитом недавно. Сделал новый проект xamarin.forms и постоянно коммитил его, но когда я сильно намудрил в проекте, решил откатиться к предыдущей версии, но, походу, очень ущербным путём. Я скачал зип файл с гитхаба моего проекта, открыл и продолжил дальше писать проект, но когда настало время коммитить, то ничего не получается, просто не загорается кнопка коммита. Может это можно как-о исправить?

Comment: `Я скачал зип файл с гитхаба` то есть ваш код не находится в каком либо репозитории, что и куда вы коммитить собрались?

Comment: Если вы работаете с гитхабом, то вам наверное нужно клонировать репозитории, а не скачивать зип архив

Comment: @tym32167 да, мне рассказали, что так надо делать(    А сейчас никак нельзя исправить, просто я уже много изменений внёс?(

Comment: Чувак, там где ты накосячил - сделай откат до адекватной версии, а там где ты скачал и написал код, скопируй и вставь в откатном проекте.

Comment: Клонируй репозиторий в отдельную папку, потом поверх этого скопируй свои изменения из первоначальной папки и коммить

Comment: Во-первых, сделайте копию каталога, в котором вы что-то делали. В нём находится архив проекта + ваши изменения. Это вам поможет не потерять ничего. Во-вторых, клонируйте в какую-либо папку проект, затем залейте содержимое из вашей копии. После этого можно коммитить. Ну, если есть права на коммит в репозиторий.

Comment: И вообще лучше юзай уже встроеный в VS инструмент - `Team Explorer`. До того момента пока не начнешь уверено использовать "голый" `git`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, сделайте копию каталога, в котором вы что-то делали. В нём находится архив проекта + ваши изменения. Это вам поможет не потерять ничего.

Вы должны понимать, что вы можете на одном компьютере иметь множество копий репозитория и каждый может иметь разные состояния. Мы хотим сохранить вашу исходную работу без изменения -- чтобы ничего в ней не поломать: работать мы будем с другой копией, правильной.

Во-вторых, клонируйте в какую-либо папку проект. Вы допустили ошибку, скачав файл с архивом репозитория, сделайте в этот раз правильно: нужно использовать команду git clone.

Подробнее почитайте в [руководствах по гит](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/git/info) или посмотрите в эти два вопроса ([раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/415739/213987), [два](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/428483/213987)) на so.

Для работы из Visual studio можете сделать следующее:

1. Открыть Team Explorer (в меню View -> Team Explorer)
2. Нажать на иконку домика
3. Выбрать пункт Clone

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вам нужно научиться выполнять эту операцию, поэтому хорошенько потренируйтесь прежде чем переходить к следующему шагу!

Далее вы можете работать с вашим новым, правильным клоном репозитория. Ключевой вопрос здесь будет: есть ли у вас право делать коммиты в проект, который вы себе забрали на комп или нет.

Если доступ есть (это самый просто вариант), то вам нужно изменить файлы вашей копии и оформить их коммитом. Делаем по шагам:

1. Берём исходный проект, который мы качали и заливаем прямо в папку правильно клонированного репозитория. Важно: проверьте, что в вашем проекте, где вы делали изменения нет скрытой папки `.git`! В принципе, её там быть не должно, но лучше проверьте, потому что именно в этой папке находится вся информация о клонированном репозитории, которая нужна для работы утилит git.
2. Даём команду `git add -A`
3. Даём команду `git commit -m "my commit description"`

Либо делаем это через интерфейс visual studio, можно две команды сделать одним махом: открыли team explorer (меню view -> team explorer), ввели текст коммита и нажали кнопку commit all:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если же доступа нет, то вам нужно уточнить у владельца репозитория как правильно делать изменения. Обычно на github это выглядит следующим образом:

- Вы делаете себе форк репозитория (был проект https://github.com/someone/project ваш логин mylogin вы делаете себе форк проекта https://github.com/mylogin/project и в нём вы являетесь владельцем)
- В форке делаете отдельную ветку, в неё вливаете изменения
- Подаёте pull request в исходный репозиторий который хозяин исходного репозитория примет (возможно, заставив вас сделать какие-либо уточнения/изменения)

Это вариант намного сложнее с непривычки, поэтому приготовьтесь к тому, что у вас не всё сразу может получиться верно или что будут возникать вопросы.